# Where is a clear list of `control strings`? When working with Lisp+Slime, the Hyperspec doc about `format` function is hard to find

Tags: lisp, format, common-lisp, slime

```
(format t "~C  ~D ???" var1)
```

Who can give a tip, How/Where in the all power *Hyperspec* can we find a list of the *control string?*

Things like this, when it's going to find some hints about the `Lisp` control string of the `format`, the *Hyperspec* always *HYPER* me.

I tried: `C-c C-d h format`, `C-c C-d h formatter`, `C-c C-d h tilds` ... They all lost me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>(i.e., `common-lisp-hyperspec-format`).  <kbd>Tab</kbd> will show a summary.  In case you forgot, it's always reachable from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>(`describe-mode`).

Answer (score 2):

The [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://clqr.boundp.org/download.html) has a nice overview of Common Lisp. Including the format functionality.